# I want to know to create a secure certificate for my UWP Project in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, uwp, certificate, appx

I have an UWP project, the certificate that I created was the option of Test Certificate that expire in 1 year. I package the app and the app security certificate say "Approved". When I send the .appxbundle to my friend because he wanted to test my app, the installer said "The certificate is not trusted Error (0x800B0109).

[image: My Friend doesn't speak spanish. He sent me a screenshot when the installer showed the error.]

Comment: My Friend speak spanish and sent me the screenshot when the installer showed the error but the error is the (0x800B0109) and I post the translate in english of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to side load an app, the machine needs to have trust for the certificate from the app developer (assuming side-loading is enabled in settings).

When you package your app within VS, there's usually a PowerShell script next to the deployment package.  If they use that script, it should prompt to install the certificate as well.

Otherwise, they can [manually import](https://windowsreport.com/install-windows-10-root-certificates/) the certificate to their `Trusted People` store in order to install the appx.

Comment: Make sure you install the certificate into the correct store - you want the "Trusted People" (yes, people) store for AppX installs.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT Yes I want the trusted people yes